# Is there are any wireless camera trigger or wireless camera controller for samsung es95 digital camera

Tags: digital, wireless, samsung

i have a digital camera ( Samsung es95). i want to control it remotely  . is there any way to do it

Comment: manual -> http://cdn.cnetcontent.com/b9/57/b95721a0-5ca5-4187-bca0-485a1ed61709.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As may know, Samsung has completely closed their camera division.  There are no parts or accessories currently available for any Samsung digital camera.

I downloaded the owner's manual from Samsung, and the list of accessories on pg 13 did not have any kind of remote control shown.  You'll need to buy a different camera.